# Alert the setter function to handle the newValue

Tags: swift, setter

Can I alert the setter function to handle the newValue?

for example:

```
var test:String{
    willSet{
        newValue = newValue+" Kitty"
    }
}

test = "Hello"
print(test) //print Hello Kitty
```

Comment: did you example even compile? did you check apple docs, before asking? do it first, please!

Comment: @LKYeung you need to name the newValue parameter `willSet (newValue)  { ... // use newValue here }` but override the newValue it is not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, you can paste it into a playground and it prints "Hello Kitty":

```
var test : String = "" {
    didSet {
        test = test + " Kitty"
    }
}

test = "Hello"
print(test) //print Hello Kitty
```

If this isn't what you were looking for, you'll need to add more detail and clarify your question.